# Why is this question closed as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

[This question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9338/how-to-use-multiple-offers-to-negotiate-a-higher-salary) is not a duplicate of the linked question.

The asker has a key distinction (which was ignored in the [edit](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/revisions/9338/2) to the title which changed the question completely... it seems people only voted as duplicate based on this incorrect title?) not present in the linked question:

- They already *verbally accepted* an offer from the company they want to negotiate with now.

All the responses in the linked question don't address this at all (in fact some of those responses don't even answer the question themselves...).

Comment: The question is to localized and should still be closed that 3 people choose dup is irrelavent to the fact that this is to localized

Comment: @Chad it's not irrelevant, because of what Rachel put in her answer - duplicates now auto-link to the different question.

Answer (score 6):

I agree that should not be closed as a duplicate to [the question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/6967/316) listed, and apparently others in the community agree as it's been reopened by 5 community votes :)

I [recently discovered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165761/158605) that questions closed as duplicates will automatically redirect unregistered users to the linked question if they try to view it, which is one reason why we only close as duplicate for *exact* duplicates, and not just similar questions.

Comment: `hich is one reason why we only close as duplicate for exact duplicates, and not just similar questions.` indeed